# How to instantiate class inside struct initializer list

Tags: c++, class, struct

Given a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    enum IndicatorType model;
    enum Cards cardIs[NUMBER_OF_CARD_SLOTS];
    uint8_t NumberOfS;
    HardwareTimers HwTimer;
    Buzzer buzzer;

}indicator;
```

and buzzer class instantiation is:

```
Buzzer::Buzzer(HardwareTimers* hwTimer)
```

How do I instantiate the struct using an initializer list?

What I have tried:

```
indicator ind =//ind is short for indicator.
{
    .model              = INDICATOR_MODEL_UNKNOWN,
    .cardIs             = {UNKNOWN_CARD},
    .NumberOfScales     = 0
};
```

Gives "could not convert 'brace-enclosed initializer list()' from 'brace-enclosed initializer list' to 'Buzzer'"

I'm unsure how to add the buzzer to the initializer list and pass it the hardware timer that is part of the struct.

Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need to typedef struct in c++

Comment: struct {. . .} indicator = { INDICATOR_MODEL_UNKNOWN, {UNKNOWN_CARD}, };   Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Comment: the style of initialization, [Designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers), you are using doesn't exist in C++ yet. Are you building for C++20?

Comment: remove the equals sign

Comment: You really should write a constructor here ...

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `indicator` a class instead? If `Buzzer` has member functions, you won't have the ability to call those from a struct "object". If you make a new `Indicator` class and instantiate it, you can create a child class of `Buzzer` and retain all the same functionality of what it looks like you are trying to do here.

Comment: Note: there are almost no differences between a `struct` and a `class`. The only one you are ever likely to notice is `class`es default to `private` access and `struct`s default to `public`. What you describe applies to `struct` as well as to `class`.

Comment: There is no difference between `class` and `struct` in C++ except the default level of access (public for struct/private for class). As such, I'm not sure what good switching between the two will do.

Comment: I think the idea of switching the two would make it easier to create the instance of both the `Buzzer` class as well as `indicator`. Personally, the only time I use structs is when they are simple groups of discrete data that don't need any functions to stand on their own. In this case, the `struct` has a `class` nested inside, why not just turn the whole thing into a `class` and afford more appropriate access permissions?

Comment: @infinity-1, structs can have different access levels in C++11 and beyond

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C++20, something like this should work:

```cpp
struct Indicator
{
    enum IndicatorType model;
    enum Cards cardIs[NUMBER_OF_CARD_SLOTS];
    uint8_t NumberOfS;
    HardwareTimers HwTimer;
    Buzzer buzzer;
};

Indicator ind // <- No equals sign
{
    .model              = INDICATOR_MODEL_UNKNOWN,
    .cardIs             = {UNKNOWN_CARD},
    .NumberOfScales     = 0,
    // ...
};
```

Comment: And how do you instantiate buzzer when it needs HwTimer passed into it?

Answer (score 0):

C++ cannot dynamically initialize an enum and any compile time solved declaration

it might be finely done by use of template statically